# Detect NetworkAvailabilityChanged in ApplicationEvents.vb

Tags: vb.net, networking

VS2022, VB.NET, WinForms app. Following some web examples I tried (in ApplicationEvents.vb):

```
  Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

  Private Sub MyApplication_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal _
      e As NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs) Handles Me.NetworkAvailabilityChanged
        Debug.Print(e.IsAvailable.ToString)
  End Sub
```

But I obtain this error:

> Error BC31029: The 'MyApplication_NetworkAvailabilityChanged' method cannot handle the 'NetworkAvailabilityChanged' event because it doesn't have a compatible signature. (translated from italian lang)

Why??

Comment: Wrong namespace and event arg. See [WindowsFormsApplicationBase.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.networkavailabilitychanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: According to [WindowsFormsApplicationBase.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.networkavailabilitychanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) it should be `e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.NetworkAvailableEventArgs` - maybe using [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) would have told you about that when you typed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Private Sub MyApplication_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.NetworkAvailableEventArgs) Handles Me.NetworkAvailabilityChanged
    Debug.Print(e.IsNetworkAvailable.ToString())
End Sub
```